# C# Combobox - "deleted entities"?

Tags: c#, database, select, combobox, dropdown

It's a struggle with any application that provides `select` fields, that are populated by a certain datasource: Everything works fine in the first place, but once the application ages, some older entries might be deleted, leading to the problem that prior `select` fields can no longer access the entity in question.

Opening a view, where a select points to an already deleted datarow will (best case) show `empty string`.

We designed our system in a way, that deletions are not real delete-operations, but only the setting of a deleted flag. (So, all the information is still there)

However, when using Databindings along with C# (or even if not) the most blatant use case is still not covered by general mechanics (I assume):

- Select-Field should show all NOT-Deleted-Entities while creating a new object containing references to the entity in question.
- Select-Field (populated the very same way) should show the "deleted" entity, if it was selected "days/months/years" ago.

Is there a "handy" solution to this?

Currently we are using a "Proxy-Method" for every datasource, which will reload the data of the deleted entity, if it's not in the "available data" collection - but it's hard to believe there is no better way to deal with this, as this problem applies for almost every language out there?

Answer (score 1):

In a normalized database you would have a constraint with `ON DELETE NO ACTION/RESTRICT` event that would prevent removal of a referenced element from the list. It would force you to decide what is to be done with the referencing rows.

With your manually-controlled deletions this could have been covered by a trigger. As none of these were implemented, you are left with only one thing to do: updating the dropdown with the selected option before rendering the UI. My approach (in `Java`, I'm not good at `C#`):

```
List<String> options = getNonDeletedWhatever();
if (!options.contains(currentEntity.getWhatever())) {
    options.add(currentEntity.getWhatever());  // This optionally inserts an outdated value
}
```

or simply:

```
Set<String> options = getNonDeletedWhatever();
options.add(currentEntity.getWhatever());      // This optionally inserts an outdated value
```

Comment: Thx. Yes that is how I currently implemented it. Just hoped there is some nice Approach, which i'm not aware of. i.e. cause usually you poplulate the select-field with "non-deleted" values, it could have been possible that you can (by code) select a non-existing entry, if you specify `Combox1.SelectedItemMustExist=false` before calling `combobox1.SelectedItem = entity.getWhatever()` on the control or whatever fancy shortcut. (I.e. implicit handling of the Source-Collection)

Comment: Real deletions on the database are not an option. If it's a customer whos deleted for any reason, all old "Orders" should still reference that customer. It just shouldn't be selectable for new Orders anymore.

Comment: I'll guess I'll extend `Combobox` and modify the `SelectedItem`-Setter accordingly, so i don't have to take care for this throughout every Combobox in the system.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by creating a list of available (non-deleted) items and if the selected item is a deleted one, then I add that item to the list.

This list becomes the data source for my dropdown.